# How is it possible that a Hamiltonian that commutes with the time reversal operator $\Theta$ has eigenstates that change sign when $\Theta$ s applied?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, time, hamiltonian, time-reversal-symmetry

$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
For example, $H=AS_z^2+B(S_x^2-S_y^2)$ where $s=1$ is time-reversal invariant, but one of its eigenvalues behaves like $\Theta\Ket{\alpha}=-\Ket{\alpha}$, while the other two stay the same. I see it's just a phase difference, but should that happen?

Comment: You can easily check that $H\Theta\vert\alpha\rangle = -\alpha\vert\alpha\rangle$, and also $\Theta H\vert\alpha\rangle = -\alpha\vert\alpha\rangle$. $\Theta$ basically acts on the eigenstates like a number (multiplying by -1), and numbers commute with operators.

Comment: @SV  $\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$ But on the other eigenstates of $H$, $\Theta\Ket{\beta}=\Ket{\beta}$. There's only one that changes sign.

Comment: But $H$ also commutes with $\Theta$ in that case (repeat what I wrote before of applying them in different order and the result will be the same). Correct me if I'm wrong but you seem to be confused by the commutativity. It means that an eigenstate of $H$ is also an eigenstate of $\Theta$, but every eigenstate can have a distinct eigenvalue.